How to avoid circular dependency with composite pattern
I'm trying to build custom filtering using expression trees and I came across circular dependency issue.
I have the following interfaces implemented:
public interface IFilterExpressionProvider
{
    Expression GetExpression(FilterCriterionRequestDto filterCriterion, ParameterExpression parameter, Type ItemType);
}

and
public interface IFilterOperatorExpressionProvider
{
    bool Supports(FilterOperators filterOperator, Type propertyType);
    
    Expression GetExpression(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, ParameterExpression parameter, object? value);
}

then I have the composite root class which is iterating over operator expression providers:
public class FilterExpressionProvider : IFilterExpressionProvider
{
    private IEnumerable<IFilterOperatorExpressionProvider> _filterOperatorExpressionProviders;
    
    public FilterExpressionProvider(IEnumerable<IFilterOperatorExpressionProvider> filterOperatorExpressionProviders)
    {
        _filterOperatorExpressionProviders = filterOperatorExpressionProviders;
    }
    
    Expression IFilterExpressionProvider.GetExpression(args)
    { 
        foreach (var provider in filterOperatorExpressionProviders)
        {
            if(provider.Supports(filterOperator))
            {
                return provider.GetExpression(args);
            }
        }
    
        throw new ArgumentException("Could not find the proper operator expression provider");
    }
}

Everything is great so far, I have different operator classes such as Equals, GreaterThanOrEquals, LessThanOrEquals, Between, OneOf etc.
The use case is that I want to be able to reuse some of the operators inside of some other operators. For example I want to use the GreaterThanOrEquals and LessThanOrEquals in the Between operator or I want to use the Equals operator in the OneOf operator and I want to use the composite pattern as I could have different variations of each operator (due to handling different data types).
Problem:
Lets take the OneOf operator example from above.
If I inject IEnumerable<IFilterOperatorExpressionProvider> into its constructor obviously I will get circular dependency exception.
Workaround:
The only workaround I found is to create a separate interface such as IEqualsOperatorExpressionProvider and inherit both IEqualsOperatorExpressionProvider and IFilterOperatorExpressionProvider in the actual implementation and also register both variations of it in the .NET IOC container. This way in the OneOf operator class I'm able to inject it as IEnumerable<IEqualsOperatorExpressionProvider> but I feel this hacky and not sure if it is okay. Both interfaces are absolutely the same obviously.
Can you recommend me a way to achieve what I'm trying to do and also tell me if my workaround is fine ?

Consider injecting the two specific operators directly into the OneOf instead of injecting the composite.

This would violate DI pattern, wouldn't it ? Also this is not going to work for me as I could potentially have different variations of the same operator(to handle different data types).

Why do you think it violates the "DI pattern"? "Also this is not going to work for me as I could potentially have different variations of the same operator(to handle different data types)." You might want to add those details to your question, as it might influence any possible answer.

@Steven
" I want to use the Equals operator in the OneOf operator and I want to use the composite pattern as I could have different variations of each operator (due to handling different data types)."
It is there.  Well the whole idea of DI is to resolve against interface and not against concrete implementation.

@Steven To elaborate further in the OneOf operator I want to use the Equals operator but I could have different variations of the Equals operator such as (Equals for dates, Equals for  floats etc.) so in my OneOf operator I want to be able to inject a collection of Equals operators and choose among them based on the date type, how I can do that given they all have the same interface ?
